# Existence of Dirichlet Inverse.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How do we show the existence of the Dirichlet Inverse of a function $f$? I know using induction that we can find a recursive form of $f^{-1}$. But I can't seem to show the existence. Any ideas?
Most sites I have searched assume the existence before giving a recursive formula.

Comment: Iff $f(1) \ne 1$ then $f^{-1}$ exists. Replace $f(n)$ by $f(n)/f(1)$ to obtain $f(1)=f^{-1}(1)= 1$. Then for $n \ge 2, \sum_{d | n} f^{-1}(n/d) f(d) = 0 \implies f^{-1}(n) = -\sum_{d |n, d > 1} f^{-1}(n/d) f(d)$ the latter being a well-defined induction formula. Equivalently you can look at $\frac{1}{F(s)}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-F(s))^k$ the latter being convergent in the ring of formal Dirichlet series.